# error unmarshalling config dump when trying to view my Istio Envoy config

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, envoyproxy

I'm running Istio on Google Kubenetes Engine. I've been following this post to [enable gRPC-web in Istio](https://medium.com/@at_ishikawa/getting-started-to-develop-a-web-application-on-gke-with-istio-for-grpc-web-1d84e084fb01). I want to view the config of my Istio Envoy proxy to check that `envoy.grpc_web` is in it, but it gives me an error:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n rev79

NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rev79-deployment-8d985d775-jx6v4   3/3     Running   1          16h

$ istioctl proxy-config listeners rev79-deployment-8d985d775-jx6v4.rev79

Error: error unmarshalling config dump response from Envoy: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []json.RawMessage
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. I gave up trying to use Istio